# How would I evaluate this double integral using change of variable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This question has me stumped and I really don't know what to do..

$B$ is the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves

$ xy = 1$ , $xy = 3$ , $x^2-y^2 = 1$ and $x^2-y^2 = 4$

How would I evaluate

$\iint_B (x^2 + y^2) dxdy$

using the change of variables

$u = x^2 - y^2$ , $v = xy$

The answer is simply 3. In most questions the substitution would either be linear or given as $x(u,v)$ instead of $u(x,y)$ as in this question and when I tried solving for $x(u,v)$ I got extremely messy equations

If someone could guide me that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can help you, but it's already night here. I have to sleep. Maybe tomorrow I'll help you if no one else does. Nightly night! ╯.╰

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to solve for $x,y$ in terms of $u,v$. I assume you're doing this in order to calculate the Jacobian determinant:

$$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|,$$

but you don't need to since

$$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right| = \left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|^{-1}.$$

Here, the right side is the reciprocal of (the absolute value of) the determinant of the $2 \times 2$ matrix obtained by differentiating $u,v$ with respect to $x,y$. When you plug this into the change of variables formula it simplifies nicely with the integrand $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: ah I didn't realize it would cancel so nicely. But this only works because there are no x and y terms left over? would i have to solve for x,y in terms of u,v if they didn't simplify so nicely? but i guess if it didn't simplify nicely you wouldn't change variables